# The Props Console Log as Undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, sanity

This is my Posts.tsx file. When I go to the browsers console it says undefined and point to this line `console.log(posts);`

```
import React from 'react'
import {sanityClient, urlFor} from '../sanity'
import { Post } from '../typings';
import Head from 'next/head'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'

export const getServerSideProps =async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post"]{
    _id,
    title,
    slug,
    description,
    author -> {
    name,
    image
   }
  }`;

  const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
}
}};

interface Props {
 posts?: [Post];
}

const Posts: NextPage = ({posts}: Props) => {
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>Posts</div>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

This is where the Post typings come form. A typings.d.ts file.

```
export interface Post {
    _id: string;
    _createdAt: string;
    title: string;
    author: {
        name: string;
        image: string;
    };
    description: string;
    mainImage: {
        asset: {
            url: string;
        };
    };
    slug: {
        current: string;
    };
    body: [object];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure getServerSideProps sets props correctly? Did you try adding console.log(posts) in there?

Comment: Is `Posts` a page component? `getServerSideProps` only works in page components.